# UITableView crash on scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Whenever i scroll my UITableView, it looks at an array to find out what to fill the next cell with, but the array is empty, causing a crash, and appears to have been released somehow. Here is my code:

.h

```
@interface HomeViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSArray *vaults;

}


@property (retain) NSArray *vaults;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

NSString *vaultsPath;

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize vaults;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    vaultsPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Vaults"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    self.vaults = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:vaultsPath error:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.vaults count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *dictionaryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                vaultsPath,
                                [self.vaults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //Crashes at this line, with the self.vaults array now empty.
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:dictionaryPath];
    cell = [AHCellCreation createCellWithDictionary:dictionary Cell:cell];

    return cell;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [self.vaults release];
}

@end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is the app crashes when you try to access the value of `vaultsPath`, which must be deallocated. Because the table view row count is based on the number of elements in the array, the method returning the cells, won't be called if there isn't any element in.
Try to retain the value assigned to `vaultsPath`, and don't forget to release it later.